# Clarification of a piece of German text

Tags: meaning, german-to-english

I have come across the following sentence:

der Geldautomat: Eine Maschine, die einem Geld von seinem Konto auszahlt.

I could not derive the meaning of this sentence. Shouldn't it have been written as one of the following:

der Geldautomat: Eine Maschine, die einem Geld von ihrem Konto auszahlt.

der Geldautomat: Eine Maschine, die Geld von ihrem Konto auszahlt.

Comment: @HalvarF Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: You can nearly translate it literally into English: "A machine, which pays out money to someone from his account".  Your  alternatives would mean: "to pay out money ... from her account", i.e. the machine would only work if the account holder is a woman, but would pay out money to everyone (men and women). I don't think such a bank would get many customers.

Comment: @user1934428 "ihrem" belongs to the machine, not a female customer.

Comment: @user1934428 If I could literally translate it, I would not ask about it. "einem" and "seinem" confused me. Your translations for my alternatives are wrong. "ihrem" belongs to the machine.

Comment: Grammatically you are right, since "Maschine" is feminine. However a machine does not have an account, and therefore I would not understand it to refer to the machine.

Comment: @user1934428 I thought that the account represents the thing from which the machine gives money to the customers. In this way, "einem" and "seinem" confused me. I supposed that "ihrem" refers to the machine.

Comment: Just for clarification: The machine transfers money from an account to the person operating the machine. The account is owned by the person who identifies himself with the bank card when operating the machine; usually, the account is owned by the withdrawer, but if I give you my card and tell you my PIN, you can get money from my account. In any case, a possessive pronoun for "account" hence refers to a real person, not a device.

Comment: @user1934428 There is no need for clarification. I know what an account is. I thought that the account represents the thing from which the machine gives money to the customers. That is so simple.

Comment: @user1934428 An account holds money. So the entity from where the machine gives money can also be considered as an account.

Comment: Just my personal opinion: In good old times, a bank clerk was giving out the money to me instead of a machine. Still, I would not asked him: "Give me money from MY account", but "Give me money from MY account". The ATM is just an electronic version of a bank clerk.

Comment: @user1934428 I have earned the "commentator" badge with your support. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whose account (Konto) is it that the money is coming from when the machine (die Maschine) disburses it to somebody?

What's meant here is not the account or cash cartridge of the machine, but the account of the person using the ATM to withdraw money. That person is refered to by "einem" and "seinem" in the original sentence.

I guess what could be confusing here is mainly the use of "einem", which in this sentence is basically the dative case of the indefinite pronoun "man".

From [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/man):

> Das Indefinitpronomen *man* hat [...] keine weiteren [deklinierten] Formen, sodass in anderen Fällen als dem Nominativ Singular auf das Indefinitpronomen *ein* zurückgegriffen wird, namentlich *einem* im Dativ und *einen* im Akkusativ.

*Jemandem etwas auszahlen* means *to disburse something to somebody*.

The possessive "seinem" in turn refers back to "einem" - the account belongs to the person who was mentioned earlier.